# how to use hide/show function of jquery in html/css website

Tags: jquery

I have created a website with html/css and javascript.
i want to add a functionality of show/hide from jquery.

I have 2 divisions course_name and course_content. there are multiple couse_names and corresponding course_content.When i click on couse_name it should show the course content.

i tried below code but nothing happens.Please let me know what needs to add or correct.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#c_name").click(function(){
    $("c_content").hide();
  });
  $("#c_name").click(function(){
    $("c_content").show();
  });
});
</script>
```

I have included jquery file "jquery-1.4.2.min"

c_name and c_content are div ID's.

html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>NAE</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/coin-slider.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-titillium-250.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/coin-slider.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hide-show.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#c_name").click(function(){
    $("#c_content").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#c_name").click(function(){
    // Check state
    if(!$(this).data('content-state') || $(this).data('content-state',1)) {

        // If content is visible (marked as 1) or if the jQuery data object is not yet available
        $('.c_content').hide();

        // Update state
        $(this).data('content-state',0);

    } else if($(this).data('content-state',0)) {

        // If content is hidden, show it
        $('.c_content').show();

        // Update state
        $(this).data('content-state',1);
    }
  });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div style="height: 361px; width: 983px;">   
       <input id="c_name" type="button" value="Master in Spare Part Management                +" class = "input1" oncick = "showstuff('hide');" /><br />
       <br />
       <div id = "c_content" class = "hidden" style="position: absolute; top: 1140px; left: 210px; width: 575px; right: 708px; ">
          <big><strong> Course Highlights :</strong></big><br />
           <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <span style = "font-size: 1.2em; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; line-height: 18px; color: rgb(35, 31, 32); font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: auto; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: auto; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;">
                        Retail Management works on this aspect. Producing large number of 
           vehicals doesn&#39;t have any meaning if there is no sale. So Sales management plays 
           vital role and it&#39;s backbone of nay dealership.<br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; NAE provides you complete 
                        mastery over sales managementwith blend of theory and practical assignments 
                        upgrading your skills to best among the industry.<br />
           <br /></span>
           <big><strong> Duration :</strong></big>
           <br />
           <br /><span style = "font-size: 1.2em; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; line-height: 18px; color: rgb(35, 31, 32); font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: auto; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: auto; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        2 Months 10 Days. Weekend (Sat &amp; Sun - 2Hrs.).</span><br/><br/>
                        <div style="background:#ededed;" >
                        <h2> Check out other <a href = "courses.html">Courses</a></h2>
                        </div>
                        <br/><br/>


                        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Is `c_content` a class or an ID? In one way or another, your selector is incorrect to begin with.

Comment: You probably need to use `$("#c_content")` or `$(".c_content")` instead of `$("c_content")`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, upgrade to a recent version of jQuery.

Then, use the `.toggle` function. It toggles the visibility of an element.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#c_name").click(function(){
    $("#c_content").toggle();
  });
});
```

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

---

EDIT: Also, make sure you've got your ID's (`#`) and classes (`.`) right.

Comment: 1. Did you add the `#`? 2. Can you update the question with some HTML?

Answer (score 0):

The hash-sign '#' for ID or '.' for class-identifier is missing:
$('#c_content').hide();
if c_content is an id.
else if its a class:
$('.c_content').hide();

As commented, it would not work that way, because you call show and hide - handlers the same time...
You should use the toggle-function of jquery.

Comment: It will still not work because it doesn't store the toggle state of `c_content`.

Comment: yes, you're right Terry, it's a start anyway. 
@Threadstarter: Use the toggle-function of jquery.

Comment: yes i tried with toggle function nothing happens :(

Comment: can you post more of your html-structure/dom-tree?

Comment: added please check and help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Try jquery `toggle()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#c_name").click(function(){
     $("#c_content").toggle();
  });
});
 </script>


  <button id="c_name" >Click me</button>

  <div id="c_content">Content </div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QPX5G/)

Comment: Did this way too ... i have added the javascript in the .js file and also included the this file in html page. ...nothing happens :(

Comment: can you post your html also,We don't know how it is

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** The answer is made under the asumption that `c_content` is a class. Otherwise, make changes to the selector accordingly.

This is because you are binding two different functions to the same handler. There is no way the script you have can distinguish between the two different states (hidden or shown). You can use the `.toggle()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#c_name").click(function(){
    // Toggle between show and hidden states
    $(".c_content").toggle();
  });
});
```

However, the solution lacks extensibility and fine-tuning, if you want to expand on your function further in the future. If this is the case, I recommend storing the toggle state as a jQuery data object.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#c_name").click(function(){
    // Check state
    if(!$(this).data('content-state') || $(this).data('content-state',1)) {

        // If content is visible (marked as 1) or if the jQuery data object is not yet available
        $('.c_content').hide();

        // Update state
        $(this).data('content-state',0);

    } else if($(this).data('content-state',0)) {

        // If content is hidden, show it
        $('.c_content').show();

        // Update state
        $(this).data('content-state',1);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that HTML structure looks like below,

HTML:

```
 <div class="c_name">name1
    <div class="c_content">
        Content1
    </div>
</div>
<div class="c_name">name2
    <div class="c_content">
        Content2
    </div>
</div>
<div class="c_name">name3
    <div class="c_content">
        Content3
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.c_content{
    display:none;
}
.c_name{
    padding:5px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    border:1px solid red;
}

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".c_name").click(function(){
    $(this).find(".c_content").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

Check the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3FuaZ/)